# Most simple and straightforward way to implement file upload in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form and I am trying to add a file upload button so that the user will be able to upload an image.

All the tutorials I have seen are using axios. I have no need for this, I am focusing on the frontend alone.

What is the most straightforward way to achieve this?

EDIT: Apologies if my question was not clear enough. Basically all I want is for a user to be able to upload an image inside that simple form, then when they press `Add`, that new object gets added to the array, which then gets rendered (I have done this part). I just need to know how to capture their `.jpg` or `.png` file or so, then add it to my object

```
interface playerInterface {
    id: number
    name: string
    club: string,
    image?: string
}
```

Comment: did not get your question can you explain more about it and if you did not want to use the axis then which one you are using for uploading the image?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get information about file just use

```
<input type="file">
```

if you want to get whole file you can use `FileReader` and read data from input

```
const [file, setFile] = React.useState();
const onChange = (event) => {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    setFile(event.target.result)
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}

return <><input type="file" onChange={onChange} /></>
```

And after that you will have your whole File in state